# Multiple Substitution

Tags: json, language-agnostic

I wish to use sed to do mulitple substitutons which are in a names.txt within a JSON file:

Part of the JSON file contains:

```
{
 "iscomplete": true,
 "totalcount": 3,
 "errcount": 1,
 "requser": "Username",
 "fileimportreqqueueid": 3,
 "format": "JSON",
 "errorfile": "http://host:port/maximo/api/fileimporterrfile/3",
 "_rowstamp": "1521573",
 "iscancelled": false,
 "reqdatetime": "2019-02-20T14:08:22-05:00",
 "name": "jason.brady@doom.com",
 "href": "http://host:port/maximo/api/os/mxapifileimportqueue/_dGVzdGxvYzMuanNvbg--",
 "pindex": 3,
 "osname": "MXAPIOPERLOC"
}
```

and part of the names.txt:

```
jason.brady@doom.com    Jason.Brady
linda.ribson@doom.com   L.Robson
Mike.graham@doom.com    Mikegraham
Phill.Lewis@doom.com    Phil.Lewis
Liam.Haggard@doom.com   LiamH
James.birch@doom.com    James.Birch
```

I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read f ; do

        email=`echo $f |awk '{print $1}' `
        username=`echo $f|awk '{print $2}'`

        sed -i 's!$email!$username!g' file.csv 

done<names.txt
```

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: what was the result of running your script? did it work? did it generate errors? did it replace the wrong strings? consider cutting-n-pasting your code into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/), make the recommended changes (especially the change for the `sed` line) and if you still have problems then update your question with your latest code and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Answer (score 3):

First, let's convert the email-name pairs into a JSON lookup table.

```sh
jq -nR '
   [ inputs | capture("^(?<key>\\S+)\\s+(?<value>.+)") ] |
   from_entries
' names.txt
```

This produces

```json
{
  "jason.brady@doom.com": "Jason.Brady",
  "linda.ribson@doom.com": "L.Robson",
  "Mike.graham@doom.com": "Mikegraham",
  "Phill.Lewis@doom.com": "Phil.Lewis",
  "Liam.Haggard@doom.com": "LiamH",
  "James.birch@doom.com": "James.Bir"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/83iB0nGKEc) on jqplay

---

This allows us to process the main file easily.

```sh
jq --argjson fixes "$(
   jq -nR '
      [ inputs | capture("^(?<key>\\S+)\\s+(?<value>.+)") ] |
      from_entries
   ' names.txt
)" '.name |= ( $fixes[.] // . )' data.json
```

or

```sh
# Accomodates a large name mapping file, but requires bash.
jq --argfile fixes <(
   jq -nR '
      [ inputs | capture("^(?<key>\\S+)\\s+(?<value>.+)") ] |
      from_entries
   ' names.txt
) '.name |= ( $fixes[.] // . )' data.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/siWk8hmFcr) on jqplay

---

You said you only provided part of the JSON file, so you'll have to adjust the program accordingly. For example, if you have

```json
[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
```

You'd replace

```
.name |= ( $fixes[.] // . )
```

with

```
.[].name |= ( $fixes[.] // . )
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7NW6OU9o5k) on jqplay

Answer (score -1):

I suggest taking look at `-f` option of GNU `sed`, it should be followed with name of file holding replacement, in your case you might create `replacements.sed` file with following content

```
s/jason\.brady@doom\.com/Jason.Brady/g
s/linda\.ribson@doom\.com/L.Robson/g
s/Mike\.graham@doom\.com/Mikegraham/g
s/Phill\.Lewis@doom\.com/Phil.Lewis/g
s/Liam\.Haggard@doom\.com/LiamH/g
s/James\.birch@doom\.com/James.Birch/g
```

and then

```
sed -f replacements.sed <file.json
```

where `file.json` is name of file with JSON. Output would be that file with replacements applied.